# Unable to load an iframe through spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, iframe

I have few links which should be opened in iframe/frame next to the links when clicked.I have a controller class which has the controlling code.

UserAccount.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<base target="frame1">
<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    color: navy;
}
iframe{margin-top:-50%;margin-left:15%;width:100%;height:300px;}
</style>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Online banking</h1>
    <div>
        <h3>Account Details</h3>
        <a href="/AccountSummary" target="frame1">Account Summary</a>
        <br/><a href="">Account Statement</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Transactions</h3>
        <a href="">Transfer Funds</a>
        <br/><a href="">Deposit</a>
        </div>
    <div>
        <h3>My Profile</h3>
        <a href="">Edit Profile</a>
        <br/><a href="">Change Password</a>

    </div>

 <iframe src="myframe.jsp" name="frame1"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UserAccount", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayUserAccount() {


        ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("UserAccount");

        return model1;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AccountSummary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayAccountSummary() {


        ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("AccountSummary");

        return model1;
    }
```

Problem here is when i click on AccountSummary,it is displaying HTTP Status 404 error.I am not able to understand what i missed in coding.Please help

Below is my dispatcher servlet:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

This is my project files screenshot:
[image: BankProject-files]

Comment: Do you have an AccountSummary.jsp (or myframe.jsp) in your WEB-INF/jsp/ folder?

Comment: Yes i have both in my WEB-INF/jsp/ folder

Comment: What does spring log when you get the 404 error?

Comment: It is some how not able to find both AccountSummary and myframe files.Console in myeclipse doesnt show up any errors while running this.On clicking account Summary this is how it displayed on page.                                                                                                         HTTP Status 404 - /AccountSummary
type Status report
message /AccountSummary
description The requested resource is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `UserAccount`-page has the URL `example.com/bankproject/UserAccount`, this link

```
<a href="/AccountSummary" target="frame1">Account Summary</a>
```

points to the URL `example.com/AccountSummary`. 
Change the value of the `href`-attribute to `./AccountSummary`.

Relative URLs starting with a single `/` are resolved by the browser relative to the URLs domain; you need a URL relative to the current directory (prefix `./`), since the request mappings are defined in the same controller.

Comment: Yes it worked .thank you.I am not aware of this concept